# Missing piece from shifter

Tags: shifter

I am missing the piece that holds the cable in the shifter body.  Does anybody know if I can buy just that part?  Are the treads standard and a could buy an inexpensive shifter and just take off this piece?
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yes you're missing a barrel adjuster.  There are two common threads, and its hard to tell which yours are in the photo.

If you have a shifter on the other side, it should have the same part in the right place.

Probably looks something like this:

[image]

and most [bike shops should be able to order the part](https://www.bikeinn.com/bike/sram-shift-lever-trigger-barrel-adjuster-x0-x9/137680714/p).